# C++ Generic Tree Comparing by Two Criteria

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I am starting to work on a generic tree and I am new to C++. I want to be able to form two trees of the same elements, but in each tree to compare in a different manner. From what I could tell if I overload < then I can only define one function. I thought I could perhaps pass a pointer to a function, but I feel like this is the wrong way to go about this.

```
template<class T, int (*Comp)(T*, T*)> class Tree
```

What would be an advisable way to try and do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, you do *not* want to specify a pointer to a function (doing so would prohibit using a function object, which is usually preferable).

The template parameter should normally be a type parameter--and in this case you almost certainly want to provide a default of `std::less<T>`, so it would look something like this:

```
template <class T, class Comp = std::less<T>>
class Tree {
     // Implementation here.    
};
```

This *will* allow instantiation over a pointer to a function, but (as noted above) will also support a function object.

Note, however, that the template parameter only specifies the *type* of thing you use to do comparisons. In a typical case, you'll need an instance of that type to do something. You'll typically specify this when you construct your object, so you'll have something like this:

```
template <class T, class Comp = std::less<T>>
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(Comp c = Comp()) : c(c) {}

    bool insert(T value) {
        if (c(value, root->value)) // if value < root->value
            // ...
        else if (c(root->value, value)) // if root->value < value
    }
private:
    struct Node { 
        T key;
        Node *left , *right;
    } *root;

    Comp c;     
};
```

So, the template parameter specifies the *type* for the thing that does a comparison. We give it a default of `std::less<T>`; that'll work nicely for built-in types, and anything else that makes `a<b` a legitimate expression (assuming we want the comparison that does, of course). If we supply a different type, it's up to use to ensure that it defines a strict weak ordering.

We then pass an *instance* of the comparison type to the constructor. Again, we specify a default value of a default-constructed instance of that type. For the common case of a function object type like `std::less<T>` or `std::greater<T>`, a default constructed object will do the right thing, so that's all we need.

For the less common case of wanting to use a pointer to a function, we have to specify the correct type as the template parameter, *and* we have to pass a pointer to the correct function to the constructor.